# spring-boot websocket server maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true) causes clients not able to re-connect after disconnection

Tags: spring-session

I have a very simple stomp websocket server using `spring-session` backed by Jdbc. The sessions are created in the database and deleted when expiration time is reached. My problem is that the *java client can connect only once*; if it disconnects (or crashes) it cannot connect anymore, even if the session is removed from the database either automatically by the server or manually.

*Can somebody tell me why the client cannot reconnect or what may be wrong in my approach?*

I need to prevent users to login more than once so in my security configuration I used `maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)`. I guessed this setting is the cause of the problem. This is the complete `SecurityFilterChain`

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
        .httpBasic(withDefaults())

        .sessionManagement((session) -> session
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
        );
    return http.build();
  }
```

I published a `HttpSessionEventPublisher` as recommended in the spring documentation

```
  @Bean
  public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
  }
```

Server configuration is very basic

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer<Session> {
  @Override
  public void configureStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    //...
  }
  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    //...
  }
}
```